# Unable to add items based on Form Parameter template under /FormsBuilder Child item in Core DB?

Tags: sitecore-forms

While creating a Form Parameter Item for a Custom Form Field in Core DB under `sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings` I faced an issue.

I wasn't able to insert the item via `Insert-> Insert from Template`. As the Insert Options for the parent item – /Settings are configured in such a way  I ended up copy-pasting another Form Parameters item in the sub children list and altering them

Also, I was able to create the items based on Form Parameter template using Sitecore Rocks under the `PageSettings/Settings` folder in `Core DB`

Is it an issue? Has any faced this? Or Did I miss something, somewhere?